# XSL How to update parameter value to calculate total

Tags: xslt, parameters

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
  <form-type>orderform-A</form-type>
    <data>
      <form-data>
         <field>
           <name>productid-1</name>
           <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
           <name>productid-3</name>
           <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
           <name>productid-4</name>
           <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
      </form-data>
   </data>
</Results>
```

On orderform-A customer can order the following products

- productid-1 (cost $5)
- productid-2 (cost $5)
- productid-3 (cost $5)
- productid-4 (cost $5)

productid-4 if ordered along with productid-2 or productid-3 is offered for free. Note the order form will only list the products ordered.

Similarly I have the following order form which also allows customers to order multiple quantities of each product :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
  <form-type>orderform-B</form-type>
    <data>
      <form-data>
        <field>
           <name>productid-w</name>
           <value>Yes</value>
        </field>
        <field>
           <name>productid-w-qty</name>
           <value>1</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-x</name>
            <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-x-qty</name>
            <value>1</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-y</name>
            <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-y-qty</name>
            <value>1</value>
         </field>
      </form-data>
    </data>
  </Results>
```

On orderform-B customer can order the following products

- productid-w (cost $20)
- productid-x (cost $10)
- productid-y (cost $20)
- productid-z (cost $10)

I want to calculate the total cost of each order so I've tried something as follows:

```
 <xsl:param name="form-type">
 <xsl:param name="total">0</xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$form-type = 'orderform-A'">
               <xsl:call-template name="orderform-A-total"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$form-type = 'orderform-B'">
                 <xsl:call-template name="orderform-B-total"/>
          </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="orderform-A-total">
      <xsl:if test="count(//Results/data/form-data/field[name='productid-1']/value) > 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$total + 5" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="count(//Results/data/form-data/field[name='productid-2']/value) > 0">
           <xsl:value-of select="$total + 5" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="count(//Results/data/form-data/field[name='productid-3']/value) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$total + 5" />
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="(count(//Results/data/form-data/field[name='productid-4']/value > 0)">
             <xsl:value-of select="$total + 5" />
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="$total" /></value>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="orderform-B-total">
           // TO DO
 </xsl:template>
```

But this doesn't work. How do I calculate the total for the different types of order forms?

Comment: Variables in XSLT are immutable. You will need to adopt an entirely different approach. Which version of XSLT can you use?

Comment: In form A can there be duplicate items? What if product4 is ordered twice, but product2 or product3 is only ordered once?

Comment: @Sebastien in form A there will not be any duplicates.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can use xslt 2.0. I thought only variable were immutable but what about parameters which is what I've attempted?

Comment: Same with parameters. You can use a parameter in a recursive template/function and update it on each call - but I don't think this would fit your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your place I would probably do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="pricelist">
    <item id="productid-1">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-2">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-3">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-4">5</item> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="price" match="item" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <total>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </total>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results[form-type='orderform-A']">
    <xsl:variable name="charges">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <charge>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('price', name, $pricelist)"/>
    </charge>   
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Results[form-type='orderform-B']">
    <!-- TO DO -->
</xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To implement a rule such as:

> productid-4 if ordered along with productid-2 or productid-3 is offered for free

you can add an empty template like:

```
<xsl:template match="field[name='productid-4'][../field[name='productid-2' or name='productid-3']]"/>
```

---

Note that there is no need for a `form-type` parameter when the input has a `form-type` element.

---

### Added:

To handle the `orderform-B` variant, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="Results[form-type='orderform-B']">
    <xsl:variable name="charges">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[value='Yes']" mode="B"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="B">
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="key('price', name, $pricelist)" />
    <xsl:variable name="qty" select="following-sibling::field[1]/value" />
    <charge>
        <xsl:value-of select="$price * $qty"/>
    </charge>   
</xsl:template>
```

And, of course, you must also add the items to the `$pricelist` variable.

Comment: why does the match expression for orderform-B template include`/data/form-data`? Also how would I implement orderform-B as that one  includes quantities?

Comment: Because I forgot to remove it. See if the edited version works for you.

Comment: that works but how can i get the quantity by its name as the product qty field may not always appear as the next sibling however the qty naming convention will always be the product name suffixed by qty e.g. productid-w-qty?

Comment: Define a key matching a field by name, and use it by adding the "-qty" suffix to the product name. --- P.S. If you have any control over the format of the input, you could save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: I've created a key for qty <xsl:key name="qty" match="field[ends-with(name, '-qty')]" use="name" /> but when I call it inside the template `<xsl:variable name="qty" select="key('qty', name)" />` it returns both the name and value. How do I get just the value? Also if the form has other fields not defined in the pricelist variable then I get error converting string to double. I'm resolving that by wrapping the charge inside  a test `<xsl:if test="key('price', dfor:name, $pricelist)">`?

Comment: I think we have veered very far off your original question. I only meant to point you in a different direction, not to write the entire code for you. If you encounter a specific problem with the implementation, I suggest you post a separate question that concentrates on that problem.

Comment: also I don't have much control over the input but I suppose the templates could be reduced to use a single one. Its just that some forms have a qty field an others don't so where a form doesn't include qty then qty can be assumed to be 1. In which case I would need to check for type of form, I'd just need to work out how to use the price * qty calculation to support both type of forms?